# Sending Emails in java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, inputstream, email-attachments, java1.4

I am trying to send email this way but i could not figure out few things

1. How do i use Input Stream object and add as a attachment.
2. How to send multiple attachments
3. How to send Multiple Attachments with HTML body

I tried below code and i could only send one attachment or HTML body

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
        new InternetAddress(to));

message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC,
        new InternetAddress(cc));
Address address[] =
        {new InternetAddress(replyTo)};
message.setReplyTo(address);
// Set Subject: header field
message.setSubject(subject);
// Now set the actual message
MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
String file = "/file.pdf";
String fileName = "attachmentName";

DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
message.setContent(multipart);
message.setContent(body, "text/html");
// Send message
Transport.send(message);
```

Comment: Do you use Spring? I can probably help more if I know this. I used to do things in a fairly manual way, but Spring has a few useful helpers.

Comment: unfortunately i do not use Spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answers 1 question

User ByteArrayDataSource it does have consutructor 
 public ByteArrayDataSource(InputStream is, String type)

This answers 2 question of your list.

You can add multiple   `MimeBodyPart` objects to `Multipart` Object

This is code taken from `Multipart.java` it adds `MimeBodyPart` objects to vector

```
public synchronized void addBodyPart(BodyPart part) throws MessagingException {
    if (parts == null) {
        parts = new Vector();
        parts.addElement(part);
        part.setParent(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you the first two work. trying to get the third one correct.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call setContent on "message", it overwrites the previous content.

Have you found the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#attach) yet?